# recommended margins?

Tags: margins

I have read why they tend to be large in the default, e.g., in
[Margin on a4 paper is too big](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141440/margin-on-a4-paper-is-too-big) , [Why are default LaTeX margins so big?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71172/why-are-default-latex-margins-so-big) .

alas, margins as wide as the defaults in latex are clearly *not* common.  yes, I know how to override them.

but I wonder whether there is a style file that is a little less adhoc than my own choices.  It could recommend / set reasonable margins for documents, perhaps based on what typical papers of this type would be...one for academic papers, one for magazines, one for books, one for letters, etc., as well as font size, etc.  That is, I would rely on experts, rather than on myself for this sort of judgment call.

Comment: Do you have evidence that text width much wider than the latex defaults is common?  (Margins are not the issue, they are just an artefact of the physical page size)

Comment: If you do not use margin notes, you might be interested in the typographic French  tradition (the so-called *Canon des ateliers*), which I explain for `a4paper` in my answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/188612/proper-page-aspect-ratio/188619#188619).

Comment: KOMA is based on some esthetic theory which might appeal to you.  Also, do you intend to print or display online?

Comment: First decide on the size of the textblock, then position it on the paper. The margins are the result of this process. Same textblock on different sized paper will result in different margins. Commercial printers will have paper sizes other than A$/letterpaper and typically trim the pages after printing so original margins are not the final ones. Try `> texdoc memdesign` Chapter 3: The Page for a broad ranging discussion.

Comment: thx for answers.

Comment: Do you have any news for us? Is your issue solved? How?